# Apache HTTPClient using TLS

Tags: java, apache, ssl, httpclient

Sorry guys, i'm searching in all the internet for this but i need someone to help me.
I've written a client for a particular server and i'm using apache http client to communicate with it.Now i've put TLS over the communication and i'd like to know how to put my client certificate into the communication in order to use HTTPs.I'm not very confident with the java keystore et similia so i need someone that helps me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apache HTTP Client and not really inclined to produce the whole keytool manual but here's the pitch : java programs can rely on a truststore to hold the certificates they should trust. The default truststore holds certificates for renowned certificate authorities, which usually is enough to validate SSL communication. However, if your certificate is self-signed, no certificate authority will validate it. Another possibility is that you don't use the default truststore. In both cases, you could use java's keytool to manipulate keystores.

Comment: thank u, i was sure it was a double way certificated communication, instead it's a one way TLS communication(only the server has its own certificate) so i can find some example to manage the keystore and validate the self signed server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The [keytool manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) describes how to manipulate keystores. The method you're interested into is -importcert.

You should first find out where the truststore your client uses is. It can be specified by the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` javaopt, or it could be your JDK/JRE installation's default, whose location is `<java_home>/jssecacerts` or `<java_home>/cacerts`.

Then you should retrieve the server's certificate. If you can you should ask the server's admin to provide it in a secure fashion. Otherwise you can contact the server in different ways so it provides its certificate, the easier being accessing its https interface on a browser.

At this point you can import the certificate in a truststore. If you use an existing truststore like cacerts, the certificate will be added as a new entry, or you can provide a path that corresponds to no file to the `-keystore` argument, in which case a new truststore with your certificate as its unique entry would be created at this location. I would recommend the latter unless your client will later communicate with CA-trusted servers.

Your keytool command should look something like that :
`keytool -importcert -alias <a name for the cert> -file <cert's path> -keystore <truststore's path> -storepass <the truststore's password>`

If you create a new truststore, the `-storepass` provided will unlock it for later uses, and must be specified to your client by the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` javaopt. If you use an existing truststore you must provide its password (I believe cacerts' is `changeit`).